# Multiple result sites (pagenumber buttons)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a website were the user types in a city (f.e.: Washington), presses search and via ajax json it gets the entries from my database. I never know how many entries it got, so let's say this time I have 40 entries in my database where it says "Washington". Now a function appends all 40 entries on the site.

**How do I get it to show only 4 entries and then add number buttons where the user can go to page "X" to see another 4 entries and so on?**

second question:

**And how do I tell the script to just add a specific amount of number buttons ( In this case just 10,  since 10*4=40 already )?**

I don't necessarily need a full code example, just a good explanation on how I can do this (without a plugin).

Here a simple drawing to clarify this:

[image: top:search, middle:entries, bottom: number buttons]

Thank you very much in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/) on tutsplus covering the kind of pagination as seen on your image. You would just need to modify the sql query in the script to match your requirements, point your ajax url to this pagination script, and ensure the results are returned as json. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like this. This tutorial looks a bit complicated. I am looking for something more simple without any extras like choosing results per page by user. But thanks to you I now know that it is called "pagination". I tried to figure out what this would be called :)Thanks. I'll google some tutorials.

Comment: There are much simpler ones. Google php mysql ajax pagination and ton's of tutorials will be at your disposal! You're welcome!

Comment: Yes, but most of them are not with JSON, for example this one ( http://bit.ly/IB3bZS ) , it seams really simple, but no json.

Comment: You can simply json_encode the results using php or manually create a json string. Play around with it. If it hangs you up, post your code here and we'll try and sort it out!!

Comment: The tutorials I read were too overloaded. I also tried jPaginate, jSimplePagination but these plugins messed up my code so I made myself a really simple one (80 lines of php). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To setup the pagination you would need to use mysql LIMIT & OFFSET, also counting the total number of results and returning that in the JSON to set the correct number of pages in the pagination.

You would also need to pass the page number in the ajax call through a GET parameter so you can set the OFFSET correctly and return the correct page.

Comment: Okay. I had thoughts on that similar to your answer. But when I have LIMIT(1, 4) (for the first page) in my PHP and I would move to the second page how would I tell the script to address (5, 8) this time? I suppose I would somehow get the current page and based on that I would set the vars pass them over and use them in the PHP file (varbegin, varend) **?** Or somehow like that **?** And secondly how would I know how many pagebuttons to dynamically add **?**

Comment: Pass the page number in a $_GET parameter to the server in the ajax call, ?page=2 then as you know how many items are on a page, set the OFFSET to offset no * page no. To get the total number of pages for the pagebuttons. You could either create the HTML on the server and return it in the ajax with the items html or return a property of the object that tells you how many pages there are in total.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some jQuery pagination plugins but they were a little buggy. So I chose pure PHP and made a really simple one myself, since the tutorials seemed a bit too overloaded to me.
I just pass `pagenr` via GET and in my script a set a specific amour of results to be displayed via `Limit $start(=0 if pagenr=1), 10`
If the `pagenr` is bigger then `"1"` it undergoes a for loop which adds up `"10"` to `"$start"` every time.
And with these values and `COUNT(*)` I do the pagination with for and if loops.